# Is ubigraph capable of node selection and custom context sensitive click menus?

Tags: opengl, user-interface, graph, 3d, window

I want to write custom callbacks and context menus for selecting individual nodes (vertices) in ubigraph. The way I see it, the user interfacing with the server will almost always want to be able to find out more about a particular vertex, and there is a definite need to be able to  do things like see if there is a path between two nodes.

Does anybody know if this can be done? I don't think it can, since the ubigraph server is closed source. Anybody with some in depth knowledge is more than welcome to provide an answer.

Here is ubigraph: http://ubietylab.net/

Comment: What is an "ubigraph"? And what does this have to do with OpenGL?

Comment: Updated with a link. Its built off of OpenGL